# How to use this VBA code to auto-filter numbers in column 2?

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

My problem is when i apply the code it hides all the values.
It works fine with text in any other column.

```
Private Sub TextBox2_Change()
    TextBox2.Value = Trim(TextBox2.Value)
    Sheet1.Range("A2:F" & Rows.Count).AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:="*" & TextBox2.Value & "*"
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your criteria is passing in a string with wildcards, but filters on numeric columns don't support wildcards.  In order to do what it looks like you're trying to do, you will need a column populated with a formula along the lines of =TEXT(B2,"#") to convert the numbers to strings and then apply your filtering to that column.